# Android 10 - open PDF with write access in Acrobat

Tags: android, pdf, android-contentprovider

I try to open programmatically a PDF file from shared storage in Acrobat Reader.
I use content provider URI and add FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION to my Intent.
But Acrobat open a writable copy and not the original file.

Comment: You have a friend: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65984804/can-not-save-pdf-file-with-fileprovider-and-external-pdf-editor

Comment: Who gave you a content provider uri?

Comment: My app use a custom content provider with grantUriPermissions attribute sets to true.